# Javascript code in main body is not working with angular template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have designed an htm page which has javascript and all has worked well, 
but when I tried to put some of the div sections of the page inside a template which would be read by 
 angularjs application all the element which require javascript to display properly were not working
 properly or displaying the element properly.
 I later discorvered that angular has its own jquery etc. But the problem is that I am using some 
 elements which are not custom made and making changes to the code may make the whole program fail.

What can I do to get all the sections to work properly?

This is the angular section

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("controls",["$scope", function($scope){
}]);

app.directive("myTemplate", function(){
    return{
        templateUrl: "template_file_with_div_section.htm"
    };
});
```

HTM SECTION

```
<div ng-controller="controls"> 
    <div my-template></div>
</div>
```

Some of the sections are using datatable etc

```
some the scripts i am using are
<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>

1. jquery.min.js
2. tables/jquery-datatable.js
3. jquery-datatable/jquery.dataTables.js
4. jquery-datatable/skin/bootstrap/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js
5. jquery-datatable/extensions/export/dataTables.buttons.min.js
```

there are over fifty different jquery scripts

**UPDATE**

When i enter the template's url through http://url/#template_name 
The template shows up in the web page so it shows that it works fine but there are sections within the template which would perform some operations (e.g. sorting etc) this sections relies on javascript which are in the main page.

These are the sections which are not working at all.

When I put the angular script after the table script. The template did not show up,
But when I put the angular script after the table script as shown above, the template showed up but the script where not working at all

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: do you have ng-app defined in html?

Comment: yes I have defined ng-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is little hard to guess what is exactly happening.

But, here are some things that you might want to consider:

- Make sure you have defined `ng-app` in your HTML.
- Also, the other part of the application (like you are saying sections) should come under your `ng-app`.
- Make sure that all your scripts are added and loaded properly.
- Each page has binding to certain controller or directive with appropriate template URL.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I have done all those yet there is no positive result

Comment: Please provide some code and more clarification about what is happening and where you are facing the issue.